# Vertically centering images to text in a multi-column container Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to know how I can vertically center align text and pictures to create a website section like this: [image]  I want align the logos and the text on the company names that are on the left of that picture. I would like to center the logos to the text next to it and their description.

HTML:

```
<div class="jarallax" data-jarallax-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3Fie3AFMrA">
    <div class="overlay subSection container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="overlay-cell clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="display-2 ">Research</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <section id="about">
     <h5 class="text-center pb-3">Discovering The Future.</h5>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <img src="assets/caolab.png" width="75" height="75"  alt="" class="img-fluid testphoto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                        <h2>The Cao Lab</h2>
                        <h3>April 2016 – Present</h3>April 2016 – Present
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 offset-2">

                        </div> 
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
        .testphoto { 
      display: inline-block; 
      vertical-align:middle;
   }

    .labname{
      display: inline-block; 
      vertical-align:middle;
      border:solid black 1px; 
    }
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Thanks a lot to @WebDevBooster for providing the solution below. However, I have realized a few issues that I've encountered. Though similar to the code posted below, I made some changes to reflect exactly what I'd like, however, It does not act in a responsive manner. In efforts to be concise and clear, i have bulleted the issues explicitly in a list:

1. As the browser window shrinks towards mobile sizes, the list becomes really narrow, and the picture/video items on the right become really small and aesthetically unpleasing. I think this is partially due to the fact that I am unable to get the picture/video items on the right move below the column with all of the bullet points to allow the list items to expand out more to the right.

   2. I'd like all elements to take up full width (width the default padding of course) of the screen as the site becomes smaller. Essentially this means that the right-most column containing the video player and the cartoon would move below the entry to its left. Something like this sort of (this is a style from another part of my site):[image: Idea of what I'm looking for] the idea being that the logo will stack above the company name (at a larger size to fill up the screen), and the picture/video on the right of the ul will stack below.
   3. I want to keep this look if the screen is large enough (desktop): [image: Ideal desktop view]

while avoiding this in mobile view: [image: problem 1]
[image]

HTML:

```
    <section id="about">
     <div class="container">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-center">Discovering The Future.</h3>
         <div class="row mt-4">

         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col">
                <div class="row">                
                    <div class="col-auto">       
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/65" alt="" class="img-fluid testphoto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col pt-3">
                        <h2>The Cao Lab</h2>
                        <h3 class="font-weight-bold pt-1 pb-3">April 2016 - Present</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="pb-3">Employ alkene metathesis to produce porous molecules valuable for encapsulation and adsorption applications</li>
                            <li class="pb-3">Prepare analytical samples, preform characterization analysis, and interpret results for molecules of interest</li>
                            <li class="pb-3">Communicate research to others by attending conferences and poster presentations</li>
                            <li class="pb-5">Devised a cost-effective method to quantify hydrogen production during evolution experiments</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 ">

                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-5by3 teensie">
                              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KPZ8HHRR1A0"></iframe></div>    
                     </div>
                </div>            
             </div>

         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-auto">
                         <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/65" alt="" class="img-fluid testphoto">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col pt-3">
                         <h2>Institut Parisien de Chimie Moléculaire
                            </h2>
                         <p class="text-primary">National Science Foundation Internation REU Program.</p>
                         <h3 class="font-weight-bold pb-3">May 2017 - August 2017</h3>
                         <ul>
                             <li class="pb-3">Conduct study on the selective deprotection of perbenzylated a-cyclodextrin to access novel functionalization</li>
                             <li class="pb-3">Synthesize molecules suitable as ligands in metal-catalysis and for improving chiral HPLC discrimination ability</li>
                             <li class="pb-3">Prepare analytical samples, preform characterization analysis, and interpret data of cyclodextrin derivatives</li>
                             <li>Submitted abstract to present at the Chemical Education Division of the 255th ACS National Meeting</li>
                         </ul>                           
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                            <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rayman/images/c/cf/Teensy.png" alt="" class="img-fluid teensie2 ">
                            </div>
                     </div>

                 </div>

             </div>

         </div>

 </section>
```

CSS:

```
        .shift{
        margin-left:20px;
    }

    .barbie{
      list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .barbieitem{
      //text-align: right;
      font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    .testphoto { 
      display: inline-block; 
      vertical-align:middle;
   }

    .joblist{
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .labname{
      display: inline-block; 
      vertical-align:middle;
      border:solid black 1px; 
    }

    .youtube {
      max-width: 300px;
      max-height: 300px;
      position: relative !important;
      float: right;

    }

    .teensie{
      top: 50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }

    .teensie2{
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nested both items (image + h2 element) in a row and their corresponding columns. The image column is given the `col-auto` class to keep it narrow and the h2 column is given the classes `d-flex align-items-center` to vertically center the items inside.

Here's the working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below to test):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-right">Discovering The Future.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-auto">
                       <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/65" alt="" class="img-fluid testphoto">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col pt-3">
                       <h2>The Cao Lab</h2>
                       <h3 class="font-weight-bold pt-1 pb-3">April 2016 - Present</h3>
                       <ul>
                           <li class="pb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                           <li class="pb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                           <li class="pb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                           <li class="pb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/140/65" alt="" class="img-fluid testphoto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col pt-3">
                        <h2>Institut Parisien</h2>
                        <p class="text-primary">National Blue text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <h3 class="font-weight-bold pb-3">May 2017 - August 2017</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="pb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                            <li class="pb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                            <li class="pb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is the idea, except that I'm trying to have "Hello Inc" (the company name) be centered with the image, and then have multiple lines below it such as "<h3>April 2016 – Present</h3> and bullet points of a job description. I tried the method above, however everything grows right to left and not vertically down. As seen in my first picture above, I'm trying to rewrite this section of my site in bootstrap where I have multiple columns, and the rightmost one I'll put some videos in related to the entry on the left.

Comment: You have contradicting images above. So, it's not really clear what you want. And even with this explanation here it is still far from unambiguous. There are at least several possibilities to interpret what you said in this comment above. So, I recommend you use some graphics editing program to create a graphic that shows exactly and without any ambiguity the desired alignment. Because I'm not really keen on redoing things over and over again just because the specs aren't clear.

Comment: Hey @WebDevBooster, sorry for the confusion. I think I have clarified my question now, and mocked up a picture of what I am trying to achieve. I updated the OP above

Comment: So, why are you then talking about "vertical centering"?? There absolutely no vertical centering of any kind. You have a very tiny bit of padding at the top. That's it. What does this have to do with vertical centering? Nothing, right? What you want is a very tiny bit of top padding for the first picture and no padding at all for the second. Correct?

Comment: The picture on the left of the company name should be centered to company name text. Currently, the picture Is aligned to the top of the text not centered to it. Padding it to get a "centered" look seems like cheating though. For both entries, if you imagine a  mid-point of the picture logo, a horizontal line across the page should traverse the center of the company title

Comment: Hmm... you don't seem to realize that your updated picture didn't explain anything. In fact, it's the exact same picture (or just as confusing) as the ones you had before. No difference (in terms of clarity) whatsoever.

Comment: You have 2 images of different height there. What you need to do is to create a model that explains things **independently** of height. In other words: Unambiguous.

Comment: What you have shown so far has absolutely nothing to do with vertical centering whatsoever. The first headline has a tiny bit of top padding and the second headline has no top padding at all. That's what I see there.

Comment: And correct me if I'm wrong, but you seem to be constantly on the look-out for half-pixel precision. There's no such thing as a half-pixel precision. The browser will round up or round down to the nearest full pixel. You might not be aware of that but that's how a browser works. Round everything up or down.

Comment: Hey @WebDevBooster, I've updated the OP with a new picture. I appreciate your help and thoughts. Let me know if this helps understand better? In the picture, notice how the logo picture is centered to the company name and along the right side of the webpage, theres another column with media associated with the company entry

Comment: I have now edited my code snippet so that it matches all parts of your picture almost to the PIXEL even though it only uses native Bootstrap 4 classes alone without any custom css.

Comment: Hey @WebDevBooster, I owe you a pizza or something. Thanks for the solid answer works AMAZING! Sorry again for the confusion earlier

Comment: Would you also happen to have some suggestions to make this behave more responsive? after adding in a picture/video column for the respective company entry, mobile does not look too good :( I've updated stuff in the OP

Comment: This is an entirely NEW question. I had answered the original one and you said you were satisfied with the solution. If you have a new question, you ought to post it as a new question. Comments are not the place for that and continuously updating your question for every new question you have is not a good idea either because that can quickly have the effect that competent users could start ignoring your questions altogether...

Comment: Also, it's always a good idea to think things through **before** posting a question. I know, quickly posting a question is fun an exciting, but thinking things through is highly recommended before posting because that can eliminate some of the issues right away.

Comment: And by the way, when posting my solution I KNEW that responsiveness is gonna be a big problem but since you didn't have any mention about the desired behavior on smaller screens, I had to assume that that wasn't a concern/requirement.